# css style not getting applied to a div in html

Tags: html, css

```css
.navigation-card{
    background-image: url("https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/facebook-square-brands-blue.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 1000px;
    width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Webpage Components</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Styles/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="navigation-card">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

It should show an image but its not. The code works when I use a web link like above for the image but it doesn't work when I give a path of a local file on my computer.

Comment: Check the path for the image, it's probably the wrong path.

Comment: What says console? Any errors?

Comment: @Konrud I have tried both relative and absolute paths and checked the path multiple times. I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan What console? Where can I see the errors?

Comment: the browser console

Comment: @user1232138 the console in the developer tools. Press F12. By the way, backslashes in path names are frowned upon. Use forward slashes.

Comment: `F12` or `Ctrl + Shift + J` if you're using Chrome (and you should be for Web Dev)

Comment: Hit F12 (to open Developer tools) - In the Console tab, if you see that the browser cannot reach a specific image (throwing an error) - or the path to the CSS file is wrong - there you go.

Comment: This is what I see in the console "The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol."

Comment: By the way, if I put your source in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1xmz2dj0/), it works, but it doesn't put the div in the center of the screen. Can you clarify what you mean exactly by "It should show an image in the center but its not"? Do you see the image, yes or no?

Comment: @MrLister I mean the image should be in the vertical and horizontal center of the background and no I do not see the image.

Answer (score 1):

You are usign image as background but you are not setting the background size, You just are setting the container size, so you have to add the next rule to your css class:

```
background-size: contain;
```

or

```
background-size: 700px 1000px;
```

From: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

"contain" ->    Resize the background image to make sure the image is fully visible

Comment: I like this answer as well.  It is a good alternative to mine, thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is it not centered is because you have set the width of the container to only 300px.  The image is taking up that full width.  If you removed the width from navigation card, it will be centered.

Alternatively, you can add the following style to the card and it will center.

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

So you'll end up with this

```
.navigation-card {
    background-image: url("https://www.sustainablewestonma.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/facebook-square-brands-blue.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to center a background image you shoud add margin: 50% auto; that make the image in the center of the page or margin: 0 auto; to make it in the top